# Finding two elements within an array with IF statement using Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, google-apps-script

I am very new to programming and I am trying to locate two consecutive values within a 1-d array in google sheets and the answers need to be highlighted in bold in the google sheet. The first value should be greater than 5 (located for example in cell D10) and the next value should be less than 4.99 (and located in E10). I have tried two methods but can't seem to get the Code to work - I don't know if I am over-complicating the problem or not. The first method was to make the row into 2 separate arrays of elements so that if element J is greater than 5, and element k (which looks at the element next to J) is less than 4.99.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var ui2 = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var data1 = ss.getRange(10,2,1,20).getValues()[0]; //Variable 1 - to find the ON value B10:U10
var data2 = ss.getRange(10,3,1,20).getValues()[0]; //to find the OFF value;
var onA = 5.00;
var on = data1 > onA;
var offA = 4.99;
var off = data2 < offA;

for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
for(var j = 0; j < 20; j++){

if(data1[i] < 5.00 && data2[j] < 4.99){

ss.getRange(10,2,1,20).setValue(data1[i]).setFontSize(12).setFontWeight("bold"); 
ss.getRange(10,3,1,20).setValue(data2[j]).setFontSize(12).setFontWeight("bold"); 
break;
} 
else {
   ui2.alert("the values are not found");
   break;
 }}}}
```

My other method was not search the cells as a single array - this works but once I add a message to a else statement to state the values are not found it would repeat this alert for the same number of times as the loop.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var ui2 = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

for(var j = 2; j < 22; j++){ // j is column number
for(var k = j+1; k < 23; k++){

var result = ss.getRange(10,j).getValue();
var result2 = ss.getRange(10,k).getValue();
var resulta = result > 5.00;
var resultb = result2 < 4.99;

  if (resulta == true && resultb == true) {

  ss.getRange(10,j).setValue(result).setFontSize(12).setFontWeight("bold");
  ss.getRange(10,k).setValue(result2).setFontSize(12).setFontWeight("bold");

  break;
  } else {
    break;
    ui2.alert('Values not found');
}}}}
```

Any help would be amazing and very greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can I ask you about the current issue of your script?

Comment: It looks that the `getRange` parameters are wrong as the A3 and C3 were mentioned but the row in the `getRange` methods is 10, not 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function findconsecutives() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  const rg=sh.getRange(10,2,1,20); 
  const vs=rg.getValues()[0];
  for(let i=0;i<vs.length-1;i++) {
    if(vs[i]<5 && vs[i+1]<4.99) {
      sh.getRange(10,i+2,1,2).setFontSize(12).setFontWeight('bold');
      break;
    }
  }
  ss.toast('not found');
}
```

I just changed the fontsize and fontweight to the cells that meet the requirements if you want to change feel free.  I don't want to.

Comment: Thank you for this code. It works much better but is making the whole row bold after the  if statement is met. Is there any way to just highlight the two cells - the first occurrence of this if statement?

Comment: It should only affect those two cells.  But anyway I don't care about the points so if you want it changed, change it yourself.